# I want to handle dynamic inputs in a form using jQuery and PHP. I'm able to add and delete input fields but failed to store them

Tags: php, jquery, html

```
these are the javascript functions i'm using

function addFac() {
    $("<div>").load("includes/facility.php", function() {
            $("#fac").append($(this).html());
    }); 
}

function deleteFac() {
    $('div.facility-item').each(function(index, item){
        jQuery(':checkbox', this).each(function () {
            if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
                $(item).remove();
            }
        });
    });
}
```

here is the HTML code:

```
<div class="facility-item well" style="clear:both;">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-1 col-sm-1 col-xs-3 padder-col">
            <input type="checkbox" class="chk-lg">
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-10 col-lg-offset-1 col-md-9 col-md-offset-2 col-sm-11 col-xs-9">
            <input class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Describe facility" name="faci[]" >
        </div>
    </div>

</div>
```

This code of html is written in a file named facilities.php and the file is included into the index.php. This is how i'm able to add and remove the dynamic input fields. But 
when I wrote the PHP file:

```
$facilities = "0";
   $faci = $_POST["faci"];
   var_dump($faci);
```

even after having  multiple facilities, it showed only one value in array.

Comment: How are you submitting the form? You have not posted jQuery code or not shown if `<form>` tag is there.

Comment: yes  i have submitted the form here  
<form name="frmProduct" method="post" action=" ">

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the working code Paste and run.

```
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    var maxField = 10; //Input fields increment limitation
    var addButton = $('.add_button'); //Add button selector
    var wrapper = $('.field_wrapper'); //Input field wrapper
    var fieldHTML = '<div><input type="text" name="field_name[]" value=""/><a href="javascript:void(0);" class="remove_button" title="Remove field"><img src="remove-icon.png"/>remove</a></div>'; //New input field html 
    var x = 1; //Initial field counter is 1
    $(addButton).click(function(){ //Once add button is clicked
        if(x < maxField){ //Check maximum number of input fields
            x++; //Increment field counter
            $(wrapper).append(fieldHTML); // Add field html
        }
    });
    $(wrapper).on('click', '.remove_button', function(e){ //Once remove button is clicked
        e.preventDefault();
        $(this).parent('div').remove(); //Remove field html
        x--; //Decrement field counter
    });
});
</script>
<form name="karan" action="" method="post">
                <div class="field_wrapper">
                    <div>
                        <input type="text" name="field_name[]" value="">
                        <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="add_button" title="Add field">add</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <input type="submit" name="submit" value="SUBMIT">
                </form>
<?php
print '<pre>';
print_r($_REQUEST['field_name']);
print '</pre>';
//output

?>
<?php
$field_values_array = $_REQUEST['field_name'];
foreach($field_values_array as $value){
    //your database query goes here
}
?>
```